# Azure App service web app health check in Free/ Basic tier showing Waiting for health check response

Tags: azure-web-app-service, health-check

I have a demo ASP.NET Core application running in Azure App service web app in Free tier. This web app is intended for health-check POC using App service health check functionality.

Surprisingly, the Health Check status always stays 'Waiting for health check response' if I keep the app in Free/ Basic tier, but as soon as I scale out the app service plan to 'Standard', it gets updated properly. I kept the app running in Free/ basic tiers for a day, just to make sure there are no delays on the status update based on the plan level, but looks like it is not related to the response delay which might have happened in lower tiers of app service plan.

I couldn't find any documentation from MS which indicates the restrictions on using Free/ Basic app service plan tier for the health-check. Any help to understand this behavior will be appreciated.

**Screenshot for App running in Free-tier**
[image: Screenshot for App running in Free-tier]
**Screenshot for App running in Standard tier**
[image: Screenshot for App running in Standard tier]

Answer (score 0):

If Your application health check is giving the status  as `Waiting for health check response`  then the check is likely failing due to an HTTP status code of 307, which can happen if you have HTTPS redirect **enabled** but have  `HTTPS Only`  **disabled**.

Comment: Thank for the help!! I have read MS documentations already and ensured that it is not the case. As mentioned in the question, it works fine if I move the web app to Standard tier , without making any other changes.